# using each with code block in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, block, each

I have action like this to add one ContestEntry record to showcase.

```
@entry = ContestEntry.find(params[:content_id])
if @entry.view_in_showcase == true
  @entry.view_in_showcase = false
  @entry.save
  redirect_to :back, :notice => "Drop design to showcase"
else
  @entry.view_in_showcase = true
  @entry.save
  redirect_to :back, :notice => "Add design to showcase"
end
```

But now I have to implement it for multiple records and I have array that includes ContestEntry records.How can I use this array with these code ?

for instance :

```
arr_showcase = [ContestEntry.first,ContestEntry.last,..]
```

How can update this array with same purpose above the text.

Comment: What exactly is the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your array is `@entries` :

```
@entries.each {|e| e.update_attribute('view_in_showcase', false) if e.view_in_showcase }
```

Answer (score 1):

First step to reuse this code is to refactor it inside a method.

```
class ContestEntry
  def toggle_view_on_showcase!
    view_on_showcase.toggle!
    save
    view_on_showcase
  end
end

# Refactor controller
if @entry.toggle_view_on_showcase!
  redirect_to :back, :notice => "Add design to showcase"
else
  redirect_to :back, :notice => "Drop design to showcase"
end

# reuse!
arr_showcase.each { |e| e.toggle_view_on_showcase! }
```